# 945P chipset and quad core CPU - does it work?

Tags: cpu, motherboard

I have an MSI 945P Neo3-f motherboard with the 945P chipset.

Does it support a quad core Intel CPU, or is it too old? I couldn't find anything useful on the net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no, Core 2 Duo is as far as it goes with CPU support for this motherboard

[Source](http://www.msi.com/index.php?func=compareindex&prod_no=1041)